# How to get decimal precision in python?

Tags: python, floating-point

Here is the situation:

- I am writing a unit test and comparing the currency which is `NUMERIC` in `PostgreSQL` with precision `(10, 2)`

My `test` has assert as

```
self.assertEquals(Decimal(89.12), user_two_transactions[0].amount)
```

I get failure as

```
AssertionError: Decimal('89.1200000000000045474735088646411895751953125') != Decimal('89.12')
```

How can I make it more precise and be sure that the amount is saved correctly in database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Initialize the Decimal with a string:

```
Decimal('89.12')
```

As you can see, 89.12 cannot be represented exactly as a float.

[Decimal construction documentation.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal)

Your other option is a `(sign, digits, exponent)` tuple:

```
In [3]: Decimal((0, (8, 9, 1, 2), -2))
Out[3]: Decimal('89.12')
```

but please don't do that without a good reason :)